# Which language is best for automating installing installers on windows and linux machines?

Tags: python, automation

Our company provide installers that needs to be installed on windows and linux machines.I have to automate this wherein these installers get installed by some script thus minimizing manual intervention.

I have come across python for this as it will be a generic solution for both windows and linux.AutoIt is specific to windows so ignoring it.

Are there another languages whose libraries are that strong to perform above task(handle OS dialogs)..

Comment: Does your installation involve wizards? or they can be done from command line?

Comment: @Waman: We need to handle both wizards and command line while installation.And installation need to be done on windows as well as linux.

Answer (score 0):

- For Command Line installations which does not involve user-interaction use a shell script or python code calling those shell commands.
- For Command Line installations which involve user-interaction use expect scripts or python's pexpect which does the same thing.
- Now, Wizard automation could be one using Robot Class Java or SendKeys Library in Python which generate keyboard events for you. To make it more foolproof you can track the installation Logs simultaneously or to keep track of errors, I would recommend you take a screenshot at each wizard screen which could help you debug later on.

Hope it helps!